# flask keeps returning "Username - This field is required. " when it is not asked

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am building on top of "cookiecutter-flask" (https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask) to build a simple Q&A app.

So I registered a new blueprint called "interview" and set the view.py to:

```
from flask import (Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, url_for,
                    redirect, session, )
from flask.ext.login import login_required
from nektime.interview.forms import InterviewForm
from nektime.utils import flash_errors

blueprint = Blueprint("interview", __name__, url_prefix='/interview',
                        static_folder="../static")


@blueprint.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def interview():
    form = InterviewForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_answer = Answer.create(text=form.text.data)
        flash("Your answer has been submitted")
        return redirect(url_for('interview.interview'))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template("interview/interview.html", form=form)
```

and form.py to:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

from nektime.models import Answer

class InterviewForm(Form):
    answer = TextAreaField('Answer',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=200)])
```

and lastly, model.py to:

```
class Answer(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'
    text = Column(db.String(400), nullable=True)
```

the html code is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>INTERVEIW</h1>
      <p>This template was created by <a href="http://github.com/sloria/">Steven Loria</a> for use with the <a href="http://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/">cookiecutter</a> package by <a href="http://github.com/audreyr/">Audrey Roy</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="/" class="">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ form.answer.label }} {{ form.answer(size=200) }}
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the results look like this: [image]

and when I click the submit button, the page shows the following and requires me to enter Username and Password, when i did not put any relevant code.

[image]

I've tried:

```
   -disabling other blueprints
   -disabling other layouts
```

but it keeps rendering with this error. I don't have a clue where that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in **cookiecutter** for **flask**, but two things I notice:

You don't need to pass `request.form` nor `flash_errors(form)`, **wtforms** automatically does it for you, so you might change to this:

```
def interview():
    form = InterviewForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_answer = Answer.create(text=form.text.data)
        flash("Your answer has been submitted")
        # I guess you want to redirect to / after form submission?
        return redirect(url_for('home')) # whatever home page?
    return render_template("interview/interview.html", form=form)
```

The failure possibly is due to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/" class="">
```

You are posting to `"/"` route, whereas this should be `"/interview"` for your `interview` view to process the **POST** request.